# How do I make it accessible from outside my local k8s through traefik

Tags: mongodb, traefik

I'm messing around with kubernetes and I've set up a kluster on my local pc using kind. I have also installed traefik as an ingress controller, and I have already managed to access an api that I have deployed in the kluster and a grafana through some ingress (without doing port forwards or anything like that). But with mongo I can't. While the API and grafana need an IngressRoute, mongo needs an IngressRouteTCP

The IngressRouteTCP that I have defined is this:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
  name: mongodb-ingress-tcp
  namespace: mongo_namespace
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: HostSNI(`mongo.localhost`)
      services:
        - name: mongodb
          port: 27017
```

But I get this error:
[image]

I know i can use a port forward, but I want do in this way (with ingress)

A lot of thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify tls parameters

like this

```
  tls:
    certResolver: "bar"
    domains:
      - main: "snitest.com"
      sans:
        - "*.snitest.com"
```

To avoid using TLS u need to match all routes `` HostSNI(`*`) ``

```
It is important to note that the Server Name Indication is an extension of the TLS protocol.
Hence, only TLS routers will be able to specify a domain name with that rule.
However, there is one special use case for HostSNI with non-TLS routers: when one wants a non-TLS router that matches all (non-TLS) requests, one should use the specific HostSNI(`*`) syntax.
```

[DOCS](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#configuring-tcp-routers)